# AngularJS - access ng-if'd form in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if

So I have a form which is in a div with `ng-if` expression. Without that `ng-if` I could just do `$scope.form`, but as I found out `ng-if` creates a child scope.

How can I access the form in the controller then?

Basically:

```
<div ng-if="whatever">
    <form name="x">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Items have access to their parent scope through $parent, or shift to `controllerAs` and you won't notice the nesting at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use model objects in scope rather than assign primitive properties directly to scope object

In controller

```
$scope.model = {
   whatever: true
};
```

Then in view:

```
<div ng-if="model.whatever">
    <form name="model.x">
    </form>
</div>
```

Now the child scope will inherit the object `model` and can therefore assign properties to it.

In the case of the form, `ngForm` will add the value in `name`to model and will create all the validation properties internally which is why it wasn't necessary to orignally create that property in the scope

Or use `controllerAs` alias and controller syntax to avoid this

Comment: Thanks, it's working! Didn't know the child scope would inherit the object! I'll use object from now on.

Comment: Understanding scope hierarchy and prototypal inheritance is really important in angular...read up on it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to set a custom validation to this field (ageRange):

```
<div ng-if=car>  
  <ng-form name="driverInfo">  
     <select name="ageRange" ng-model="driver.ageRange" ng-change="checkAge(this)" required></select>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

To do so, I needed to access the field via the scope, what otherwise would be done with `$scope.driverInfo.ageRange.$setValidity`.

But as it's wrapped by an `ng-if`, I passed `this` as argument, so I can access it from the controller like this:

```
$scope.checkAge = function(model) {
  if ($scope.driver.ageRange.value === 'BELOW_MINIMUM_AGE') {
    model.driverInfo.ageRange.$setValidity('adult', false);
  }else{
    model.driverInfo.ageRange.$setValidity('adult', true);
  }
};
```

In this case, `this` is the childScope itself, not the DOM element.

Hope this helps others, cheers!